# Remove incomplete/broken files in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, file-writing

In my py-script I obtain data from async cycle and dump it into the file,

```
from csv import writer
import asyncio

with open('my_file', 'a', newline='') as file:
   async for item in item_feed:
      processed_item = ...
      keys = ...
      ...
      ...
      dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, keys)
      dict_writer.writerow(processed_item)
```

For some reasons it can happen that an exception appears during this process. When an exception occurs, the created file is not correct. I would like to find the most appropriate way to do the following:

> If an exception occured, then delete obtained file

The (incomplete) list of possible exceptions is given below:

- `exception OSError()`
- `exception KeyboardInterrupt`
- `exception ConnectionError`
- `exception BrokenPipeError`

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: please share exception you encountered.

Comment: @rok I have tried to add some examples. But the question is quite general: I would like to understand is it possible or not to delete "broken" file if any exception occured during async  cycle?

Comment: Delete file on KeyboardInterrupt would make for some interesting support calls

Comment: Surround the `with` block in a `try..except` and delete the file in the exception handler. Have you followed a tutorial on exceptions and how to handle them?